# What are the four climbing knots used by Jim Bridwell?

Tags: rock-climbing, knots

Long & Gaines *Climbing Anchors* says:

> Jim Bridwell, one of the most experienced climbers in the
>   history of the sport, uses only four knots for any and all climbing situations. Better
>   to learn a few knots well, than a multitude of knots poorly.

[Source](https://books.google.com/books?id=lQoQAQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA103&dq=Jim%20Bridwell%2C%20one%20of%20the%20most%20experienced%20climbers%20in%20the%20history%20of%20the%20sport%2C%20uses%20only%20four%20knots%20for%20any%20and%20all%20climbing%20situations.%20Better%20to%20learn%20a%20few%20knots%20well%2C%20than%20a%20multitude%20of%20knots%20poorly.&pg=PA103#v=onepage&q=%22Jim%20Bridwell,%20one%20of%20the%20most%20experienced%20climbers%20in%20the%20history%20of%20the%20sport,%20uses%20only%20four%20knots%20for%20any%20and%20all%20climbing%20situations.%20Better%20to%20learn%20a%20few%20knots%20well,%20than%20a%20multitude%20of%20knots%20poorly.%22&f=false)

It then goes on to describe 6 different knots.  Which are the 4 that Bridwell used?  Is  there really a set of 4 that work in every situation?

Answer (score 2):

> But is there really a set of 4 that work in every situation?

I'm a [reasonably experienced climber (I currently lead HVS outdoors, about 6b indoors/sport)](https://www.ukclimbing.com/logbook/showlog.php?id=141813), I can tie 7 knots (counting 3 variations on the figure eight as one) (from memory anyway). This covers pretty much every situation I've ever encountered. The knots I know are:

- [Figure eight (various)](https://www.animatedknots.com/fig8follow/)
- [Clove hitch](https://www.animatedknots.com/clovehalfhitches/index.php)
- [Alpine butterfly](https://www.animatedknots.com/alpinebutterfly/index.php)
- [Flat Overhand knot](https://www.animatedknots.com/flatoverhand/index.php)
- [Prusik](https://www.animatedknots.com/prusik/index.php)
- [Double fishermans](https://www.animatedknots.com/doublefishermans/index.php)
- [Double overhand](https://www.animatedknots.com/doubleoverhand/index.php)

With these knots you should be able to cover every situation you need, from hauling to setting up a belay. Here's some of them (clove hitch,figure eight and double overhand(stopper)) in action:
[image]

***Can anyone spot the mistake in the above photo?*** I posted this photo on Facebook and a climbing instructor friend pulled me up on it! Said it's safe but could be safer.

Comment: How do you escape the belay without a knowing the munter and mule knots? I always use a water knot to make a loop in webbing, what do you use? Do you really never use a girth hitch? While I have only used a barrel hitch a couple of times, how would you haul a keg of beer to the top of the climb?

Comment: @StrongBad And I thought I was a not very good, but quite complete all-around climber except for bigwalling - I apparently am not, I haven't hauled a keg of beer to the top of a climb yet. Then again that might be a bigwall thing?  
 - I'd say if you know the double fisherman, you don't need to list the double overhand as a separate knot, as it's basically a requirement of the former. And while both have their places alpine butterfly and flat overhands are replaceable in my use. With that you'd be down to four. Then again I agree with StrongBad that a Munter is essential - so 5 again.

Comment: Girth hitch I wouldn't count as a "knot", It's just a loop. I know  a munter but never use it. To shorten webbing an overhand is fine. Getting a keg to the climb would involve carrying a keg to the climb, so I'd rather go the pub. :)

Comment: No one spotted the mistake then? I'm off work for a week now, if no one guesses I might add a question with a bounty! :)

Comment: @Liam The only thing I see is slight multi-directional loading of the carabiner?  I don't know what all these ropes are connected to, though. I would love to take quizzes on this stuff.  "Spot the mistake in this rig" is a better instructional tool than just reading a book about how to do things right.

Comment: Yeah the bottom carbiner isn't loaded which is why it looks like it's side loaded, this is the one attached to the seconds belay rope and the second isn't climbing, which is why I could take a photo, it's not that. @endolith

Comment: The ropes are attached to gear in rock. This is a belay stance at the top of a single pitch trad climb.

Comment: Oh go one then, [answers on a postcard](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/21877/what-is-wrong-with-this-belay-setup)

Answer (score 1):

I doubt he only knew 4 knots. Looking at online photos, is difficult, but in this photo

[image]

I think I can see a double fisherman's on the cord on the back of his harness, a figure eight on a bight on the blue haul line, a girth hitch on the last pin and possibly a water knot. I have also found pictures of him at an anchor with a bunch of clove hitches, but it is unclear who tied them. Maybe he never used them, but I doubt that.

I would also expect him to know the Prussik, or some other friction knot for hauling and a Munter hitch for belaying, but cannot find them in photos. He probably also knew a square knot (and hence a granny knot) as well as a simple overhand knot for backing up his eight on a bight, because most people know these knots. Finally, even if he used a swami belt, I would be surprised if he couldn't tie a bowline on a coil.

This is still a relatively small number of knots.

Comment: It says "used" not "knew"

Comment: @endolith I am pretty sure he setup a haul system and belay at least once.